# How to write css/xpath selector for a specific icon in specific row in table that is built from div's?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to access "Edit" icon for a specific element in the dynamic table.

HTML -

```
        <div class="fixedDataTableLayout_rowsContainer" style="height: 323px; width: 1882px;">
            <div class="fixedDataTableColumnResizerLineLayout_main fixedDataTableColumnResizerLineLayout_hiddenElem public_fixedDataTableColumnResizerLine_main" style="width: 0px; height: 325px; left: 0px;">
                <div class="fixedDataTableColumnResizerLineLayout_mouseArea" style="height: 325px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_rowWrapper" style="width: 1882px; height: 48px; z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_main public_fixedDataTableRow_main fixedDataTableLayout_header public_fixedDataTable_header" style="width: 1882px; height: 48px;">
                    <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_body">
                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 48px; width: 0px; left: 0px;">
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 48px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 48px; width: 1882px; left: 0px;">
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 48px; position: absolute; width: 1882px; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 48px; width: 916px; left: 0px;">
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell cell-header text-center" style="height: 48px; width: 916px;">
                                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">
                                                    <div class="sort-by ">Facility
                                                        <i class="fa fa-sort-undefined" style="margin-left: 3px; position: absolute; top: -3px;"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 48px; width: 866px; left: 916px;">
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell cell-header text-center" style="height: 48px; width: 866px;">
                                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">
                                                    <div class="sort-by "># of rooms
                                                        <i class="fa fa-sort-undefined" style="margin-left: 3px; position: absolute; top: -3px;"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 48px; width: 100px; left: 1782px;">
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1" style="height: 48px; width: 100px;">
                                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" style="left: 0px; height: 48px;"></div>
                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 48px; width: 0px; left: 1882px;">
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 48px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_rowWrapper" style="width: 1882px; height: 60px; z-index: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 48px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;">
                    <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_main public_fixedDataTableRow_main public_fixedDataTableRow_even public_fixedDataTable_bodyRow" style="width: 1882px; height: 60px;">
                        <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_body">
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 1882px; left: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 1882px; z-index: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;">
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 916px; left: 0px;">
                                        <div data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" field="name" class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell undefined" style="height: 60px; width: 916px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">uitestsfacility</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 866px; left: 916px;">
                                        <div data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" field="roomCount" class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell text-center" style="height: 60px; width: 866px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">1</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 100px; left: 1782px;">
                                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell text-center" style="height: 60px; width: 100px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="Edit Facility"></i>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o disabled" data-tip="Cannot be deleted due to rooms or devices belonged to this facility"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="" style="left: 0px; height: 60px;"></div>
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 0px; left: 1882px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_rowWrapper" style="width: 1882px; height: 60px; z-index: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 108px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;">
                    <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_main public_fixedDataTableRow_main public_fixedDataTableRow_highlighted public_fixedDataTableRow_odd public_fixedDataTable_bodyRow" style="width: 1882px; height: 60px;">
                        <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_body">
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 1882px; left: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 1882px; z-index: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;">
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 916px; left: 0px;">
                                        <div data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" field="name" class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell undefined" style="height: 60px; width: 916px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">testsearchfacility</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 866px; left: 916px;">
                                        <div data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" field="roomCount" class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell text-center" style="height: 60px; width: 866px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">1</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 100px; left: 1782px;">
                                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell text-center" style="height: 60px; width: 100px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="Edit Facility"></i>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o disabled" data-tip="Cannot be deleted due to rooms or devices belonged to this facility"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="" style="left: 0px; height: 60px;"></div>
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 0px; left: 1882px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_rowWrapper" style="width: 1882px; height: 60px; z-index: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 168px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;">
                    <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_main public_fixedDataTableRow_main public_fixedDataTableRow_even public_fixedDataTable_bodyRow fixedDataTableLayout_hasBottomBorder public_fixedDataTable_hasBottomBorder" style="width: 1882px; height: 60px;">
                        <div class="fixedDataTableRowLayout_body">
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 0px; left: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 1882px; left: 0px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 1882px; z-index: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;">
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 916px; left: 0px;">
                                        <div data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" field="name" class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell undefined" style="height: 60px; width: 916px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">AutomationFacility 1249.0</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 866px; left: 916px;">
                                        <div data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" field="roomCount" class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell text-center" style="height: 60px; width: 866px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">0</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 60px; width: 100px; left: 1782px;">
                                        <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap1 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap1 text-cell text-center" style="height: 60px; width: 100px;">
                                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap2 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap2">
                                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_wrap3 public_fixedDataTableCell_wrap3">
                                                    <div class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="Edit Facility"></i>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o " data-tip="Delete Facility"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="" style="left: 0px; height: 60px;"></div>
                            <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 60px; width: 0px; left: 1882px;">
                                <div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup" style="height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 0px; z-index: 2; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E.g. I need selector for edit icon in the row for AutomationFacility 9341.0. This element is being created in my test and then I need to click "Edit" icon for it. In this case, I never know the position of the element.

In provided HTML edit icon is in row 183
I was trying to find it by something like this:

```
 $(byXpath("//*[text()='"+facilityName+"']/i[@class='fa fa-edit']")).click();
```

But it doesn't work and I get error that selector is incorrect.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work". Do you get an error or an incorrect result?

Comment: do not post an image of the html, post the html itself please

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean that I cannot click into this element and get error that my selector is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the **Edit** *icon* with respect to the text **AutomationFacility 1249.0** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  //div[@class='public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent' and contains(.,'AutomationFacility 1249')]//following::i[@class='fa fa-edit' and @data-tip='Edit Facility']
  ```

**Note**: You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the icons and text that you mean are not in one div, this is your html pattern :

```
div
   div
      text
   div
   div
      text
   div
   div
      edit icon you mean
    div
div
```

I tried using `contains` and `preceding-sibling`, like this :

```
facilityName = "AutomationFacility 1249.0";

$(byXpath("//*[contains(@class,'fixedDataTableCell') and ./preceding-sibling::*[contains(@class,'fixedDataTableCell')]//div[contains(text(),'"+facilityName+"')]]//i[@class='fa fa-edit']")).click();
```

Try change value the `facilityName` with you expected.

Comment: I never know which number my element is going to have because I might have at some point 10 or 15 rows and if I always click on [3] I will click into wrong element

Comment: please provide the `HTML`.

Comment: added HTML to the description

Comment: @MikhailSiekhin i've updated the code, please try again.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) XPath axis and [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function combination like:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'AutomationFacility')]/descendant::i[@data-tip='Edit Facility']
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Going forward consider including HTML code of the page, not the image, the chance of getting comprehensive answer will be much higher

Comment: trying to use ur xpath but still get Element not found error.

Answer (score -1):

Try using below given xpath

```
//div[@class='fixedDataTableLayout_rowsContainer']//child::div[3]//child::div[1]//child::div[1]//child::div[1]//child::div[2]//child::div[1]//child::div[3]//child::div[1]//child::div[1]//child::div[1]//child::div[1]//child::i[@class='fa fa-edit']
```